# How to create Named Ranges using a loop in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, named-ranges

I would like to create named ranges in my Excel sheet which should be copied to another worksheet later.
I have created a code that names the ranges like this:

```
Sub Sample1()

Dim RangeName As String

    RangeName1 = Worksheets("DB_Elements").Range("B3")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName1, RefersTo:=Worksheets("DB_Elements").Range("B3:V14")
    
    RangeName2 = Worksheets("DB_Elements").Range("B17")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName2, RefersTo:=Worksheets("DB_Elements").Range("B17:V28")
```

However, this needs to be repeated another 85 times. So I need a loop in my VBA that would create each time a new named range based on the "B" cell value which is always offset 14 rows down. The named ranges always consist of 12 rows and 21 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Sample1()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  With Worksheets("DB_Elements")
    For i = 1 To 85
      j = (i - 1) * 14 + 3
      ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=.Range("B" & j), RefersTo:=.Range("B" & j & ":V" & (j + 11))
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```